# merge png with mp4 ffmpeg missing audio

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, overlay, mp4

I use ffmpeg to merge mp4 and png, I use two way:

1. use command

   String cmd = "-y -i " + in.mp4 + " -i " + in.png + " -filter_complex [0:v][1:v]overlay=0:0[out] -preset veryfast -map [out] -map 1:0 -map 0:0 -codec:a copy " + out.mp4;

**output file missing audio:**

2. use command:

   String cmd = "-y -i " + in.mp4 + " -i " + in.png + " -filter_complex [0:v][1:v]overlay=0:0[out] -preset veryfast -map [out] -map 0:a -codec:a copy " + out.mp4;

=> There is audio but some mp4 file cannot merge with png file
Log: Stream map '0:a' matches no streams.

What is my command missing here ?

Comment: Can you give full result of ffprobe?

Comment: You should show the complete console output/log of each command. Otherwise it is not possible to provide an answer.

Comment: I found problem here. If video don't have sound, we can't put map 0:a for it (Log: Stream map '0:a' matches no streams.). Now i check to detect this video have audio or not to make filter correct. But it make more time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first, you need use **ffmpeg** to check `mp4` info. Then you will select command with **0:a** or not

```
            ffmpeg.execute(("-i " + filepath).split(" "), new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {
                    boolean hasAudio = false;

                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(String s) {

                       if (s.matches("^\\s+Stream.+Audio.+")) {
                            hasAudio = true;
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {

                    }
                });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this solotion will work but we must run two command with ffmpeg.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with one command:

```
String cmd = "-y -i " + in.mp4 + " -i " + in.png + " \
              -filter_complex [0:v][1:v]overlay=0:0[out] -preset veryfast \
              -map [out] -map 0:a? -codec:a copy " + out.mp4;
```

The `?` teels ffmpeg to only map the stream if it exists.